# Counter is not incremented when controlling signal changes

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I implemented a simple counter 0 to 255 design in VHDL. It works as expected on the FPGA board, but when I simulate it in Modelsim, the counter does not add when I force `key(0)` to change. Any thoughts?

```
library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY PROC_TEST     IS
  PORT(
    CLOCK_50: IN STD_LOGIC;
    KEY: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    LEDR: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END PROC_TEST;

ARCHITECTURE MAIN OF PROC_TEST IS
  SIGNAL COUNTER: INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 255;
BEGIN

  LEDR(7 DOWNTO 0)<= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (TO_UNSIGNED(COUNTER,8));

  PROCESS (CLOCK_50)
  BEGIN
    IF (KEY(0)'EVENT AND KEY(0) = '0')THEN
      COUNTER<=COUNTER + 1;
    END IF;
  END PROCESS;
END MAIN;
```

Comment: I beautified your code and improved your text, hope it was ok. Just reload the page in your browser or click on the notice above your question.

Comment: thank you, I could not see the changes you made though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal `KEY(0)` is missing in the process sensitivity list. This is typically indicated by a warning, when you synthesize your code for an FPGA.

A process only executes/resumes:

- once after simulation startup,
- whenever one of the signals in the sensitivity list changes.

Thus your process only executes when `CLOCK_50` is changing, but not when you force a change on `KEY(0)` in the simulator. Thus, you have to change your code to:

```
PROCESS (KEY(0))
```

After making this change, the simulation output is at follows with a 10 MHz clock applied to `KEY(0)`:

[image: simulation output]

---

**Further remarks:**

As you see in my simulation screenshot, the signals `LEDR(9)` and `LEDR(8)` have an undefined ('U') value. This happens because you forgot to assign them in your architecture. This should be indicated by synthesis as well. Often the synthesizer just assign '0' (logic low) to the outputs, which can be achieved explicitly with:

```
LEDR(9 downto 8) <= "00";
```

The other input signals have an undefined value in my simulation because these are unused inputs and I have not applied any waveform to it.